# jQuery and jQueryMobile bestpractices: is there a way to generalize for reusability?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Now that jQueryMobile is mature enough, I'd like to do a Website, and to have a specific folder for mobiles.

Is there a bestpractice to follow to do the maximum of the job once and to have my website, and my mobile website share the maximum code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to say it but a lot of this is still being worked out as people learn to work with JQM. I find the best way to discover these practices is via stackoverflow, and the Jquery Mobile Forums.  There are a few books out but nothing with a lot of best practice info yet.

I also recommend following the jquery mobile blog. They always list resources tips, extensions etc.

Comment: Ok so I'll try to do it on my own then I'll write a book about it (just kidding) =)  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I think that's what a lot of people are doing(writing a book) :) - but the resources literally grow by the day.